# How to use Stream method in jparepository

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I am new to Spring.How to use Stream method in jparepository.I want to get data from jparepository. I configure applicationcontext.xml also.I am using spring 4 version

My Repository class

> ```
> @Repository
>  public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long>{
>     @Query("select   c from  Customer c")
>     Stream<Customer> getAllFirstNames();
> }
> ```

my mainclass.java

> ```
>  @Transactional
>   public class VaadinUI extends UI  {
>       @Autowired
>       private  CustomerRepository repo;
>          System.out.println("enter into try block");
>           Stream<Customer> customers= repo.getAllFirstNames();
>           System.out.println("Customers"+ customers); 
>     }
> ```

now i got error like
   **You're trying to execute a streaming query method without a surrounding transaction that keeps the connection open so that the Stream can actually be consumed. Make sure the code consuming the stream uses @Transactional or any other way of declaring a (read-only) transaction.**

How to slove that issue.How to call repository stream method in maincalss.java
I add **@Transactional(readonly=true)** till i got same error.
please help me out!

Answer (score 2):

You need to do couple of things.

1. Processing data with a Stream requires us to close a Stream when we finish it.
   It can be done by calling the close() method on a Stream or by using try-with-resources

   ```
    try (Stream<Customer> customers = repo.getAllFirstNames()) {
       System.out.println("Customers"+ customers); 
    }
   ```
2. Make your method calling this function as `Transactional(readonly=true)`